# Flutter seperate Class in two files

Tags: flutter, class, dart, extension-methods

I have quite a big `class` so I would like to separate this one `class` in multiple `files`.

This is what I tried:

```
class BackendService {
...
}

extension BackendServiceAddMemory on BackendService {
...
   void function() {}
}
```

But with this I can not call `BackendService().function()`. This is not working but that is my goal.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

ok so... my solution was actually correct. But Flutter or VSCode failed to suggest the import. Importing it manually fixed it

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29794298)

Comment: @LW001 fair enough

Comment: Well I am looking for something similar but also require to access setState in the other file also. Let me explain -  The thing my single file is becoming very large so i need to split them into small parts, but the issue I face is that whatever method I try , I can not use setState outside the main class which I am trying to split, If you got any simple method that can solve my problem, Please share, it would be highly appreciated !!!